# React updating during transition error and I am not updating state inside render

Tags: reactjs, state

I am trying to get rid of this error but cannot seem to find why its triggering. Here is my code for a role based routing component. I call the check to see what the users role is and based on the accepted roles array passed in, if they match then set state for granted true. If no roles are passed in I pass them to the route meaning it was not protected. If no user then send them to login. If they are not granted then I send them home.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserContext from '@Context/User';

const RoleRouting = ({
    component: Component,layout: Layout, roles, ...rest
  }) =>{

const [granted, setGranted] = useState(null);
const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
const history = useHistory();

useEffect(() => {

    grantPermission(roles)

 }, [roles]);

 const grantPermission = (requestedRoles) => {
    if(requestedRoles != undefined){
        requestedRoles.map(function (role) {
                if(user){
                    if(role === user.is_admin){
                        setGranted(true);
                    }else{
                        setGranted(false);
                    }
                }
        });
    }else{
        setGranted(true); 
    }
};

return(
    <div>
        {granted != null &&
            <div>
            { granted && user &&
            <Route
            {...rest} render={props => (
                <Layout>
                <Component {...props} />
                </Layout>
            )}
            />
            }
            { !granted && user &&
                history.push('/')
            }
            { !granted && !user &&
                <Redirect to="/login" />
            }
            </div>
        }
  </div>
)
}

export default RoleRouting;
```

I changed the flow of the state updating like below and it is still complaining...

```
const grantPermission = (requestedRoles) => {
    let grantFlag = false
    if(requestedRoles != undefined){
        requestedRoles.map(function (role) {
                if(user){
                    if(role === user.is_admin){
                        grantFlag = true
                    }
                }else{
                    grantFlag = false
                }
        });
    }else{
        grantFlag = true 
    }

    setGranted(grantFlag)
};
```

Comment: What is in `roles` and what is in `user.is_admin`? And where/how are you using the `RoleRouting` component ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli roles is an array prop - exampe [0,1] and user.is_admin is either a 0 or 1; The component is a wrapper around my react router routes so that i pass in component, path, and the roles that are allowed. If no roles are set then I automatically grant it. make sense?

Comment: First issue, the `grantPermission` will only work for the last value in the `roles` array, since it does a `map` and inside you have an if/else.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli see the edits I made above... still no luck.